# drupal 7 GRA4 install

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-7

i installed drupal 7.0 and module Libraries API after that i try install this module (https://www.drupal.org/project/gra4) but on page where module must be work i see this displays the inscription 
"Please make sure the GRA4 library is installed in the libraries directory. GRA4 library can be found here. Place files in sites/all/libraries/gra4/ (or sites/example.com/libraries/gra4 if you have a multi-site installation)."
i try put files in this way  sites/all/libraries/gra4/ but after that shows a white screen on the page - what I need to do that would be earned module

Comment: or may be anybody can help me to make a list of modules to make it work. I need - 3 groups users, messages, polls and opportunity to add files - this is all

Comment: check watchdog and see what the error is.